# Parse google location data into R dataframe

Tags: xml, r, parsing

The data is roughly this:

```
<Document>

    <Placemark>
        <name>Latitude User</name>
        <description>location history</description>
        <styleUrl>#multitrack</styleUrl>
        <gx:Track>
            <altitudemode></altitudemode>
            <when>2014-03-14T09:02:17.647-7:00</when>
            <gx:coord>X Y Z</gx:coord>
            <when>2014-03-14T09:02:18.647-7:00</when>
            <gx:coord>X Y Z</gx:coord>
        </gx:Track>
    </Placement>
</Document>
```

I am trying to read the `<when>` and `<gx:coord>` data into an R data frame as separate columns. I want to read the `<when>` and the `<gx:coord>` tags into separate columns of the data frame. X, Y and Z are GPS numeric coordinates. There is only one set of `<gx:Track>` s

I have gotten as far as

```
library(XML)
data <- xmlParse("history-03-14-2014.xml")
```

xmlToDataFrame doesn't seem to be able to navigate down to the `<gx:coord>` and `<when>` nodes though and I can't work out how to access the values.

Thanks

Comment: I think you need to expand on the example a bit more - are there repeated gx:Track elements or repeated Placemark elements or what? Is the X Y Z actual numbers? What do you want in your data frame?

Comment: This is a perfect example of why asking for "small representative examples" is such a crock. If this is a kml file then there are several namespace declarations in the header. If you upload the whole file somewhere (Dropbox?) and post a link in your question, maybe someone can help you.

Answer (score -1):

I not sure how rest of the file look, but I assume that gxtrack is repeated many times and you want to extract this points. Try regex:

```
require(stringi)
file <- stri_paste(readLines("file.xml"),sep="",collapse="")
stri_match_all_regex(file,"<gx:Track>.*?<altitudemode>(.*?)</altitudemode>.*?<when>(.*?)</when>.*?<gx:coord>(.*?)</gx:coord>.*?</gx:Track>")
```